# Loop in MySql, or alternative?

Tags: mysql, database-design, loops, entity-attribute-value

I have a MySql db with innoDB tables. Very simplified this is how two tables are layed out:

> Table A:
>
> - controlID(PK)
> - controlText
>
> Table B:
>
> - controlOptionID(pk)
> - controlID(FK to table A)
> - controlOptionType
> - controlOptionValue

So many controlOptions(table B) can reference one control(giving that control multiple options). But for each option two rows are made in table B:  one row with controlOptionType = "linkToCreator" and controlOptionValue = (an ID to the template it was made from*). And the other row type = "optionSelected" and value = "true"(or false).

> - = its a pretty complicated setup, but basically instead of set columns we are making dynamic ones by means of the type being what the column would have been called. So I couldnt link to the template with FK.

So now I need to select every control(which will have 2 controlOptions linking to it) where the one controlOptionValue value is true or false(depending on what i need) and the other controlOptionValue is an text ID that I specify.

What I think is the best way to do it is a

```
SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE controlOptionType = 'linkToCreator'
```

Then do a loop over that result set saying:

```
SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE tableB.controlID = (the controlID in this iterations row) AND tableB.controlValue = 'true'
```

But maybe thatls really inefficient, and either way I have no clue how to do that. It would be great if I could get a single query(i.e. not using stored procedures) that I specified templateID and true or false and it gave me a row result if it didn't find anything.

BTW this is for a search in our application with will need to go through TONS of rows so performance is paramount. And yes, I know the setup isnt the greatest...

Thanks :D

Comment: This approach is called EAV: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model

As you mentioned, it's not a good approach for high performance.

Comment: ...Or data integrity.  Or support for constraints.  Or data types.  Or any relationally normal forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
SELECT * FROM tableA AS A
LEFT JOIN tableB AS ctrl1 ON (A.controlID = ctrl1.controlID AND ctrl1.controlOptionType = ? AND ctrl1.controlOptionValue = ?)
LEFT JOIN tableB AS ctrl2 ON (A.controlID = ctrl2.controlID AND ctrl2.controlOptionType = ? AND ctrl2.controlOptionValue = ?)
```

Comment: Ha! Awesome, thanks so much :D

Three last things, is it possible to make it so it only returns the result if it finds both ctrl 1 and ctrl 2? At the moment it returns null for ctrl1 and/or ctrl2 instead of just removing that row.
And, if I wanted to to do another join(to something tableA links to) do I just add it as usual to the last line?

Comment: 1. Change left joins to to inner joins
2. Yes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_A 
LEFT JOIN Table_B
ON Table_A.ControlID = Table_B.ControlID
WHERE Table_A.controlOptionType = 'linkToCreator
```