# Multiple return types from NHibernate

Tags: sql, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Earlier I asked this question: [Loop in MySql, or alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339477/loop-in-mysql-or-alternative/3339494#3339494)
I got a great answer and it does work. Now in my application I am using NHibernate(in C# .NET 3.5) as the DAL. I dont really know how to deal with multiple return types, so I tried the following:

```
    var session = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession();
            IQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery(@"SELECT * FROM tableA AS A
                                                    LEFT JOIN tableB AS ctrl1 ON (A.controlID = ctrl1.controlID AND ctrl1.controlOptionType = ? AND ctrl1.controlOptionValue = ?)
                                                    LEFT JOIN tableB AS ctrl2 ON (A.controlID = ctrl2.controlID AND ctrl2.controlOptionType = ? AND ctrl2.controlOptionValue = ?)")
                                                                    .AddEntity(typeof(nodecontrol));



            IList<tableA> aList = query.List<tableA>();
            IList<tableB> bList = query.List<tableb>();
```

This worked with aList. But when I add another "AddIdentity" for tableB it dies when it gets to the aList part because its the wrong type of object. 
Now I presume I can just do a linq WHERE on that List to get the types for each(but I dont know how), and after that, how do I differentiate from the two instances of tableB that I will get per row?

Preferably I would like to end up with 3 lists(tableA, tableB, tableB) where the rows are inline so aList[4] will be the same result row as bList1[4] and bList2[4].

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Multi Query](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/05/NHibernateMutliQuerySupport.aspx) is the solution that you're looking for.